# Best practise for REST-API authorization using OAuth 2.0 / OpenID Connect access vs. ID token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

In the last weeks I read a lot about OAuth 2.0 / OpenID but some things are still not clear. I understand the purpose of these protocols: while OpenID issues an ID token, usually JWT, which tells me who the user is, OAuth 2.0 issues an access token but this tells nothing about the identity of the user. I also read that the purpose of the id token is using it in the client software showing for example the user’s name or even his profile picture.

I also read the strong advice, that when I implement my own REST-API, the access token should be requests as HTTP header authorization and not the id token.

Well, I have the need that also the called API needs to know the user’s identity. For example, if a user calls a POST action which creates a new record, I like also to store the email address of the user calling the API.

Another reason why the API needs to know the identity is our current setting: We use Azure Active Directory where we assign groups to a user. When we need to check the authorization for an API call, we check if the user is assigned to a certain group. It would be great, if the assigned groups are provided as claims of the access token, but unfortunately this is a lacking feature of Azure AD B2C. There already exists [this feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b). But unless this is available, we need to call the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve the assigned groups of a user. And when calling the Graph API, we need also to know the identity of the user calling our API.

So, what do you suggest as best practice for API authorization, especially when managing the users and access rights via Azure AD/Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C does not provide the feature to add custom claims or more specifically - in your case - user group information when issueing tokens. At least not out of the box.

But I think what you need can be achieved by using [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started) in combination with a corresponding [Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-profiles-overview).

Basically, it allows you to change the behaviour of the standard AD B2C user flows by applying custom behaviour. With that it is possible to let Azure AD B2C request the user group information via a Technical Profile so that custom claims are received during the B2C user flow (e.g. login) that can than be included in the issued tokens (id token or access token).

As you require information from Azure AD I think you can use the [Azure Active Directory Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile) for your solution.

For a more detailled explanation and a tutorial for setting up a custom policy see here: https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/

But before you start using custom policies I recommend to make sure the built-in claims (attributes) provided by Azure AD B2C (which can be included in the issued tokens out-of-the-box via configuration features of B2C) don't already include the claim types that you need. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes

For instance, the email address of the user which you mentioned is already provided as built-in attribute.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. To summarize: we should use access tokens but include the email address and perhaps also full name as claims and add the assigned groups via custom policy as custom claim. We will try this.

Comment: It is not unusual to see an email address in access tokens. Often the email address is used as unique username and represented as the subject claim (*sub*) in the access token. And yes, I suggest to include the group information (e.g. group ids) via the custom policy approach.

Comment: If including the full name of the user is okay really depends on your privacy policies. I would include as little information about the user as possible in your tokens. So user information that you need only for some use cases or very rarely should be queried on demand, e.g. via an user info endpoint or a custom user service. The same applies for the email address of course, make sure you really need it for your authorization logic to be available in the token. Don't just put everything into the token just for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth being aware also that you can keep access tokens confidential and use a [Claims Caching Design](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) in your API to manage looking up Graph User Info when a new access token is first received.

This is a portable and easy to extend solution that will work with any Authorization Server. Some resources of mine that may give you some ideas:

- [Azure Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/30/azure-active-directory-setup/) blog post
- [Some Relevant Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/tree/master/api/src/host/oauth) in case useful